extend jpa entity to fetch extra field
I have been using hibernate for few years now with spring JPA. And I am a big fan of the JpaSpecificationExecutor,
which allows you to filter tables quite elegantly.
However, I have few cases where I want to load some extra fields and I would expect the code to be a simple as.
MyEntityWithExtraField extends MyEntity {
@Fromula("....")
Integer extraField;
}
(or instead of @Formula use @Subselect then)
create a repository for this class and use it, without duplicating all the code and without changing the main entity to be MappedSuperClass and have 2 children and change all its references.
I am sure there is a good reason why you can't just extend, but this would improve the dev experince so much. Can someone explain to me why it is like this ? And if there is a better way of doing what i am trying to do.
